# Do Cobalt fullly support the remote debug function as Chrome dev tool on Windows?

Tags: cobalt

Is the remote debug function of Cobalt fully supported(Such as Source/Network/Timeline/Console items)  as Chrome dev tool on Windows? 
We can connect the Cobalt on the ARM device with chrome on Windows PC by remote debug function of Cobalt,  and we have found it can only inspect the html tags in the Elements catalogue, it can NOT run the javascript in the Console(eg location.reload()), it can NOT capture a timeline in the Timeline catalogue(When reload the YT page, it will disconnect to the platform), and it also can NOT see any source files in the Sources catalogue, so is there any one who can help to point out exactly which functions are supported in the Cobalt remote debug function? If some functions are not supported yet, is there a plan to support them in the near future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cobalt does not fully support the developer tools.

It serves them and has support for the protocol and DOM/CSS inspection, but, as you have discovered, more work is required as of Cobalt 6 to support JS debugging, network and the other features. Yes, the plan is to support more of the developer tools, but there are no specific dates yet.